# AlertDialog custom EditText view and copy-paste menu

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm using the AlertDialog inside a DialogFragment from appCompat 22.2.1 to make something like the following.

[image: Dialog]

But as you can tell the copy-paste menu features are pretty messed up. What can I do to bring the copy-paste menu bar from the background to the foreground? And Also how can I change the "PASTE" Label color?

This is my xml Style for the dialog

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue_500</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/grey_200</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_gray</item>
</style>
```

And My dialog code inside The DialogFragment

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertCompat = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogStyle);
    alertCompat.setTitle("Hello wtf");
    alertCompat.setView(R.layout.add_mac_dialog_frag);
    alertCompat.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, this);
    alertCompat.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, this);
    return alertCompat.create();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the AppCompat problem documented by [AOSP Issue 170105](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170105).  The fix will be in the M release (v23) of AppCompat.

Comment: Ah Thanks a lot for the info. I guess we will have to wait for an update

Answer (score 0):

OK since this is a known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170105) and the appCompat devs love to break a little something every time and then take forever to release new fixes, I ended up using the amazing [material dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library

[image: Material Dialog lib]

Comment: Glad you found a work-around.  Your criticism of the AppCompat devs is inappropriate and unjustified.

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed by their approach. Every new update breaks something in my code. But that last one was really something else. 3 Things are broken now. I may have worked the dialog thing arround using the 3rd party lib but I have to wait for their next update for the other 2 bugs to be fixed -.-

Comment: Understood. Your revised answer and comment describe your frustration well.